Unable to display or print the real time token response generation on streamlit frontend
I am creating rag ChatBot but unfortunately on cli callback function is displaying realtime generating responses. I want to display the real time generating responses on streamlit frontend. Like ChatGPT does. Real time response printing token by token. Anyone can provide solution to this.?
Expecting real time token response to be printed on streamlit frontend.
